# Google play store support Web App?

Tags: web, google-play

Is Google Play Store support Web Apps?
Is We can upload our Web Apps on Google Play Store?

I know Google Play store Support Android Apps but I dont get a answer that Google Play Store Web Apps or not.

Comment: What is your definition of a web app?

Comment: Mobile Web App build with responsive layout, jquery, PHP etc

Comment: Using a framework like ionic, cordova, or?

Comment: Yes, I thing may or may not. because web apps are also developed without any framework.

Comment: this is trivial to try. what has failed after you tried? also, offtopic as its not about programming. see [how to write a good stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)